How to fix issue installing scann Kodal scanmate i940 driver
How to install this driver if during the installation come up this message from terminal:
This scanner uses OpenUSB and TWAIN Data Source Manager open source
software, which are already included in this package.

Source code can be downloaded from:
- OpenUSB: http://openusb.wiki.sourceforge.net
- TWAIN Data Source Manager: http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-dsm

Checking software versions, please wait...
   Description:         Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
                        ('Ubuntu' 24.04 - Ubuntu x86_64 .deb)
   Kernel:              v6.8.0
   mono:                not supported (v6.8.0.105)
   mono-winforms:       not supported
   SANE:                installed
   XSANE:               installed
   hal:                 not installed (using libudev0)
   libudev0:            installed
   OpenUSB:             not installed
   TWAIN DSM:           not installed


******************************
The installer cannot determine which mono package to install
on your computer or you have an incompatible version.
The installer typically needs v2.4+ or v4.x.
This package is required by the TWAIN driver's user
interface (i.e. UI). However, the UI is not required
in order to scan.
This means you can continue without this package if your
scanning application does not need the UI. If you
continue, the UI will be disabled and you will need to
re-run this installer in order to enable the UI.

NOTE: To get the proper package, you will need to exit
      this installer and install the package yourself.

Do you want to continue this installation, without the UI? (y/N) y


******************************
The installation is ready to begin (no software was been installed yet).

NOTE: scanner must remain unplugged or off during install

Do you want to continue with the installation? (y/N) y


******************************
Copying installation packages to temporary directory: /tmp/kds_i900
Please wait...



******************************
Installing OpenUSB, please wait...

Selecting previously unselected package libopenusb.
(Reading database ... 236923 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libopenusb_1.1.16-0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libopenusb (1.1.16-0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopenusb:
 libopenusb depends on libudev0 (>= 147); however:
  Package libudev0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libopenusb (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libopenusb

OpenUSB installation FAILED


Press the 'Enter' key to exit this installation...

